# PCRE replace markup style

Tags: php, css, regex, pcre

I need a PCRE expresssion (regex) to match and replace a certain attribute and value related to a markup element, something like this :

```
<div style="width:200px;"></div>
```

into

```
<div style="width:100px;"></div>
```

What I have now, parsed by [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is the style content in plain text, like this :

```
width:200px;
```

How can I match the CSS attribute and replace it with the new values in PHP?

Cheers!

Comment: Which params are you passing, `width` and `100px`?

Comment: the value only .. I want to find a attribute and replace it's value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
([^\s:]+)[\s:]+([^:;]+)
```

will extract the values around the colon into backreferences 1 and 2.

```
([^\s:]+)[\s:]+(\d+)(\w+)
```

will do the same but extract the value (200) and the unit (px) separately.

```
if (preg_match('/([^\s:]+)[\s:]+(\d+)(\w+/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $attribute = $regs[1];
    $value = $regs[2];
    $unit = $regs[3];
} else {
    // no match
}
```

Comment: +1 That's a nice solution, but it can't cope with a space after the colon, which is quite common.  This should sort it: `/([^\s:]+)[\s:]*(\d+)(\w+)/`

Comment: Thanks - I have edited my answer. I used `[ \t]` instead of `\s` to be a bit more explicit - or could there even be newlines there?

Comment: Good question. I haven't checked the specs, but instead I have just altered some CSS on one of my test pages. Newlines both before and after the colon don't appear to bother Firefox in the slightest, so I think less explicit is the way to go.

Comment: @yoda: Well, what do you want to replace with what?

Comment: nevermind, I found better to just separate attributes and respective values into arrays and reorganize the css string, no need for regex replacement :)

Answer (score -2):

```
preg_replace('~width:200px~', 'width:100px', $subject);
```

Comment: that only works if the attribute and value are expected to be like that.